# Unable to view SQL Server Agent in ssms (express edition 2012 service pack1)

Tags: sql-server

I'm aware that SQL Server Agent can't be visible in SSMS Express edition but I've read somewhere that it is possible in Express edition 2012 Service Pack 1. I searched everywhere on the web for confirmation but no luck.

Here is my current ssms version:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (Intel X86)  Feb 10 2012
>   19:13:17  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Express Edition on
>   Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

My SQL Server Agent Service is up and running fine. Please advise if it's possible to view Agent in SSMS or I have to go for standard edition?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No - SQL Server **Express** (with or without service packs) just doesn't support SQL Server **Agent** - never has, probably never will.

Comment: Thank you for saving my day!